# firebase_auth/unknown null error show in Firebase OTP Authentication Failed on release build

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

**`[firebase_auth/unknown] null`** shows error in the app run on release mode [tap to see the flutter release app runtime erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aouVU.png)r

Please Inform to how to swole this error because debugging complete work but release app in Firebase mobile authentication  not working